# Updating a Drop down list with Jquery from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a  list that I need to fill using a JSON collection of object. Here is what my action is returning:

```
public ActionResult GetProductCategories()
        {
            var categories = _entities.ProductCategories.ToList();

            var result = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                result.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = category.CategoryName, Value = category.CategoryId.ToString()});
            }

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is what I've come up with for my javascript, gathered from various sources:

```
function loadCategories() {
            $.getJSON("/Admin/Product/GetProductCategories", null, function (data) {
                var selectList = $("#subCategories");

                $.each(data, function(index, optionData)
                {
                    var option = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);
                    selectList.add(option, null);
                });                
            });
        }
```

But it doesn't appear to be working, and isn't giving any errors. Whats the best practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: What does your response from the server look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was wondering what are you trying to achieve in this next lines of codes,

```
var option = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);
selectList.add(option, null);
```

are you trying to create an `option` then add it on `select`? if so, do it like this, use `.append()`

```
selectList.append(option);
```

with that, I'm still assuming `new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);` is creating a new `option`, in jQuery it would be like this `var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);`

---

added notes for `.add()`,

```
var selectList = $("#subCategories"); // creates jQuery object selectList.
selectList.add(option, null); // selectList is jQuery object,
                              // so when you call .add(), you're calling jQuery's `add()`.
```

a workaround is this,

```
selectList[0].add(option, null); // you can use [0] to convert it into DOM object.
```

difference between:

- DOM `select` object's [.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/select.add)
- jQuery object's [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

Comment: +1 - The `.add()` is certainly a problem, good catch...I kept seeing `.options.add()` but that's not what he's calling here.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery fails silently if it doesn't like the JSON data coming back from the server. Point your browser at /Admin/Product/GetProductCategories and look at the result. Make sure it doesn't have any html tags and make sure there are double quotes around the key names.

Comment: Yep, the data coming back is valid - it seems to be how I'm adding to the selectList.