# How to Process Ajax Result (Struts2)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp, struts2

I'm extremely new to Ajax but have managed the following code but cannot fathom how I process the results to be set into the ajax response then processed.

I have this which sends the correct value of a select dropdown to the Action method:

```
$('#selectRegionList').on('change', function() {
var request = $.ajax({
url: "/cars/annCreateEdit!updateLocs.jc",
type: "POST",
data: {id: this.value}
});
```

Which correctly comes to this method in the action and loads a list of Objects (some attribues of the objects are String name, String description, Long id)

```
public String updateLocs() throws SQLException {
String regionName = findParamStringValue("id");
if (annoEditParams.getRegionStr() == null) {
addActionError("error.region.id.null");
} else {
Region region = new Region();
region.setName(regionName);
criteria.setRegion(region);
annoEditParams.setRegion(jobsService.loadRegion(criteria));
locations = annoEditParams.getRegion().getLocations();
}

return "jsonResult";
```

}
I have the jsonResult for the action mapped to:

```
<result name="jsonResult" type="json">
<param name="root">locations</param>
<param name="location">/WEB-INF/jsp/locs.jsp</param>
</result>
```

And finally the correct result is being called (I know because the existing list (if I load one using the regular submit button) is being cleared)

```
request.done(function(response) {
$('#selectLocationList option').remove();
//what do i do here ? :o(
});
```

- but I've no idea what I have to do next to

The part of the page I'd like to populate is a struts2 select tag as follows:

```
<s:select
key="label.select.location"
list="annoEditParams.region.locations"
name="annoEditParams.locationStr"
listKey="name"
listValue="description"
multiple="false"
size="1"
value="%{annoEditParams.locationStr}"
disabled="%{annoEditParams.region.locations.size == 0}"
id="selectLocationList"
cssClass="span2"
/>
```

1: access the correct parameter that contains the list that I've loaded
2: if I have to 'set' that list in some special object for access back on the jsp 
3: maintain my sanity :-/

Assistance/guidance would be very much appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispense with saving your Ajax in a request variable and just define a success callback in the Ajax call directly, if you want:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/cars/annCreateEdit!updateLocs.jc",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id: this.value},
  success : function(response)
  {
       $('#selectLocationList option').remove();
       $('#selectLocationList').html(response);
  }
});
```

If your response was an HTML snippet that is just a list of options `<option value='x'>x</option><option value='y'>y</option>` etc., you could just set it as the innerHTML of the specified select tag, as above. Since you've chosen to return JSON, now you have to parse the JSON from the variable `response` on the client-side first using something like what's found [here (Updating a Drop down list with Jquery from JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809167/updating-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery-from-json).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I believe I know what you mean by the extra jsp to receive the html - however I need it to go into a struts select tag (in order to maintain functionality for 'traditional' post and page refresh for users that have JS disabled (for accessibility etc)) - I've edited my question to add the s:select I'm using.

Comment: @KenAlton The ID of a select button is the ID of a select button, regardless of how the button's HTML is being generated.

Comment: Thank you guys. I did precisely that - return the result as a String - iterating the results from the DB and assembling "<option value='" + l.getName() + "' >" + l.getDescription() + "</option>"; adding that to a List<String> and it works.  I just assumed there was a more elegant way of doing it in jQuery.  However, thank you both for the answer and more thanks for the extra understanding you've enabled me to glean from it.